# Extracting values from nested rules in JSON data

Tags: list-manipulation, import, replacement, coding-style, json-format

I have been using Mathematica to analyse some data from the StackExchange API. It is conveniently available in JSON form, which Mathematica interprets as replacement rules. However, some of the rules are nested as the right-hand side of an outer rule, as you can see in the case of `badge_counts` here:

```
Import["http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=mathematica",
   "JSON"][[2, 2, 10]]

(* Out[1]= 
{"accept_rate" -> 75, "account_id" -> 395497, "age" -> 41, 
 "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 35, "gold" -> 0, "silver" -> 11}, 
 "creation_date" -> 1326833982, "display_name" -> "Verbeia", 
 "is_employee" -> False, "last_access_date" -> 1331949804, 
 "last_modified_date" -> 1330990001, 
 "link" -> "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8/verbeia", 
 "location" -> "Sydney, Australia", 
 "profile_image" -> "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3df2379fc0221bb0281c0d608542bd84?d=\identicon&r=PG", 
 "reputation" -> 3571, "reputation_change_day" -> 0, 
 "reputation_change_month" -> 857, 
 "reputation_change_quarter" -> 3475, "reputation_change_week" -> 605,
 "reputation_change_year" -> 3475, "user_id" -> 8, 
 "user_type" -> "registered", 
 "website_url" -> "http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica"}
*)
```

Users without any badges don't have this nested rule. To handle both cases I am doing something like this to get the badge counts in a flattened list, so each row of the final list corresponds to a user of the site:

```
getUserData[page_Integer] := Module[{ad},
  ad = Import[
     "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?page=" <> 
      IntegerString[page] <> 
      "&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=mathematica", "JSON"][[2,2]];
  If[Length[ad] > 0,
   Join[Most[#], {"bronze", "silver", "gold"} /. 
       Last[#]] & /@ (({"display_name", "creation_date", "reputation",
          "reputation_change_week", "is_employee", "last_access_date",
          "user_type", "badge_counts"} /. ad) /. 
      "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 0, "silver" -> 0, 
        "gold" -> 0}), {}]
  ]
```

Which I can then build up into a list of all users and their stats like this:

```
Monitor[
 pageM = 0;
 resultM = 
  FixedPoint[Join[#, getUserData[++pageM]] &, {}];,
  StringForm["Loading page `` ...", pageM]
 ]
```

The final output is list of vectors that look like this:

```
resultM[[10]]
(*Out[2]= {"Verbeia", 1326833982, 3571, 605, False, 1331949804, "registered", 35, 11, 0} *)
```

My question is: is there a more concise or elegant way to write the `getUserData` function, without need a `Join` *and* three separate `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) constructions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to get rid of all but one `ReplaceAll`. First, you need to remember that `ReplaceAll` tests each `Rule` in order, so to deal with the missing "badge_counts" condition, you can simply add that to the list, as follows

```
{"display_name", "creation_date", "reputation", "reputation_change_week",
 "is_employee", "last_access_date", "user_type", 
 "badge_counts"} /. Flatten[{ record, 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 0, "silver" -> 0, "gold" -> 0} }]
```

where `record` is one user record. Since, `"badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 0, "silver" -> 0, "gold" -> 0}` is listed after the one in the user info, it will only be used if there is no `"badge_counts"` in the user info.  To eliminate the "badge rules", I would remove them using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) and one more replacement rule and a final `Flatten`:

```
{"display_name", "creation_date", "reputation", "reputation_change_week",
 "is_employee", "last_access_date", "user_type", 
 "badge_counts"} //. Flatten[{ record, 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 0, "silver" -> 0, "gold" -> 0},
   Rule[_, a_]:> a}] // Flatten
```

which returns for your info

> {"Verbeia", 1326833982, 3571, 605, False, 1331949804, "registered", 35, 0, 11}

**Edit**: Originally, I used a slightly different approach instead of `Rule[_, a_]:> a`. I am reproducing it here, for the curious:

```
{"display_name", "creation_date", "reputation", "reputation_change_week",
 "is_employee", "last_access_date", "user_type", 
 "badge_counts"} /. Flatten[{ record, 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 0, "silver" -> 0, "gold" -> 0}}] // 
Block[{Rule=#2&}, Flatten[#]]&
```

which relies on the [property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/52) of `Block` to temporarily override the behavior of `Rule`.

**Edit 2**: Here's one more alternative which should reduce it to a single pass, unlike `ReplaceRepeated`. This method, also, eliminates the need for the final `Flatten`

```
Clear[killRules]
killRules[a : {_Rule ..}] := Sequence @@ a[[All, 2]]

{"display_name", "creation_date", "reputation", "reputation_change_week",
 "is_employee", "last_access_date", "user_type", 
 killRules["badge_counts"]} /. Flatten[{ record, 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 0, "silver" -> 0, "gold" -> 0}}]
```

Answer (score 19):

*Update: [Athanassios](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18906/athanassios) correctly pointed out that my attempt to set defaults doesn't work*.
The problem appears to be that the absence of the element from the first list (`ad`) causes the defaults list to never be checked.  A condensed exhibit:

```
ad = {"accept_rate" -> 80, "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 39, "silver" -> 9}};

defaults = {"age" -> Missing[], 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> #, "gold" -> #, "silver" -> #} &@
    Missing["NotAvailable"]};

OptionValue[{ad, defaults},
  {"accept_rate", "age", "badge_counts" -> "bronze", "badge_counts" -> "gold"}]
```

> OptionValue::optnf: "Option name "badge_counts" -> "gold" not found in defaults ..."
>
> ```
> {80, Missing[], 39, "badge_counts" -> "gold"}
> ```

One can use the modified form `OptionValue[{}, {ad, defaults}, . . .]` to avoid the message but the result is still incorrect.  I am sorry I missed this problem when I posted this answer.

---

It seems to me that this is the correct way to extract values from a nested list of rules:

#### Data

```
ad = {"accept_rate" -> 75, "account_id" -> 395497, "age" -> 41, 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 35, "gold" -> 0, "silver" -> 11}, 
   "creation_date" -> 1326833982, "display_name" -> "Verbeia", 
   "is_employee" -> False, "last_access_date" -> 1331949804, 
   "last_modified_date" -> 1330990001, 
   "link" -> "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8/verbeia", 
   "location" -> "Sydney, Australia", 
   "profile_image" -> 
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3df2379fc0221bb0281c0d608542bd84?\
d=\ identicon&r=PG", "reputation" -> 3571, 
   "reputation_change_day" -> 0, "reputation_change_month" -> 857, 
   "reputation_change_quarter" -> 3475, 
   "reputation_change_week" -> 605, "reputation_change_year" -> 3475, 
   "user_id" -> 8, "user_type" -> "registered", 
   "website_url" -> "http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica"};
```

#### Defaults

include default values for any rules that might be missing

```
defaults = {"badge_counts" ->
      {"bronze" -> #, "gold" -> #, "silver" -> #}& @ Missing["NotAvailable"]};
```

#### Extraction

```
OptionValue[{ad, defaults}, {
   "display_name",
   "creation_date",
   "reputation",
   "reputation_change_week",
   "is_employee", "last_access_date",
   "user_type",
   "badge_counts" -> "bronze",
   "badge_counts" -> "silver",
   "badge_counts" -> "gold"
}]
```

> {"Verbeia", 1326833982, 3571, 605, False, 1331949804, "registered", 35, 11, 0}

Comment: +1, I hadn't thought of `OptionValue`.

Comment: @rcollyer is there any way to set a default value for *any* missing option?  That would make this more elegant.  Nevertheless I think this is the best way to deal with nested rules; getting a value for e.g. `a -> b -> c -> d` is pretty hairy otherwise.

Comment: The only way I'm a aware of is via `SetOptions` which isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: @rcollyer how would you do it via `SetOptions`?

Comment: Exactly, the problem. `SetOptions` requires a symbol to be associated with the options. In this case, it isn't clear what symbol you'd use.

Comment: @rcollyer sorry, I wasn't clear; can you set a *default value* that applies to *all options* (without having to list all of them), even for a symbol?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard your solution is great but it seems to me default values work only for non-nested values. I have tested this by creating another set where "badge_counts"->"gold" value is missing and I am getting an error message Option name badge_counts ->gold  not found in defaults for \
{{display_name ->Stones ,accept_rate ->80,account_id \
->495497,badge_counts ->{bronze ->39,silver ->9}},{age \
->Missing[],badge_counts ->{bronze ->Missing[NotAvailable ],gold \
->Missing[NotAvailable ],silver ->Missing[NotAvailable ]}}}. >>

Comment: You could use the form `OptionValue[defaults, ad, {"accept_rate", "age", 
  "badge_counts" -> "bronze", "badge_counts" -> "gold"}]` instead. It will complain that `defaults` is missing a rule for "accept_rate", but that is easy to fix.

Answer (score 6):

The introduction of [`Assocation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assocation.html) brings a powerful new way to handle this problem.

- Version 10.2 [provides for](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87879/121) import of JSON as nested associations without use of `ToAssociations` by using the format `"RawJSON"`.

```
(* archive data *)

ad = {"accept_rate" -> 75, "account_id" -> 395497, "age" -> 41, 
   "badge_counts" -> {"bronze" -> 35, "gold" -> 0, "silver" -> 11}, 
   "creation_date" -> 1326833982, "display_name" -> "Verbeia", "is_employee" -> False, 
   "last_access_date" -> 1331949804, "last_modified_date" -> 1330990001, 
   "link" -> "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8/verbeia", 
   "location" -> "Sydney, Australia", 
   "profile_image" -> 
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3df2379fc0221bb0281c0d608542bd84?d=\ identicon&r=PG", 
   "reputation" -> 3571, "reputation_change_day" -> 0, "reputation_change_month" -> 857, 
   "reputation_change_quarter" -> 3475, "reputation_change_week" -> 605, 
   "reputation_change_year" -> 3475, "user_id" -> 8, "user_type" -> "registered", 
   "website_url" -> "http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica"};
```

Convert to nested Association (reference: [Converting hierarchies of rules to associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55745/converting-hierarchies-of-rules-to-associations/55746#55746))

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
asc = ToAssociations[ad];
```

Query a value:

```
asc["badge_counts", "silver"]
```

> ```
> 11
> ```

Missing values are automatically handled:

```
asc["badge_counts", "platinum"]
```

> ```
> Missing["KeyAbsent", "platinum"]
> ```

Perform multiple lookups at once:

```
lookups = {{"display_name"}, {"creation_date"}, {"reputation"}, \
{"reputation_change_week"}, {"is_employee"}, {"last_access_date"}, {"user_type"}, \
{"badge_counts", "bronze"}, {"badge_counts", "silver"}, {"badge_counts", 
    "gold"}, {"badge_counts", "platinum"}};

Extract[asc, lookups]
```

> ```
> {"Verbeia", 1326833982, 3571, 605, False, 1331949804, "registered", 35, 11, 0, 
>  Missing["KeyAbsent", "platinum"]}
> ```

More advanced queries are easy.  With current data:

```
data = Import[
    "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=\
mathematica", "JSON"] // ToAssociations;
```

Find my current bronze badge count:

```
data // Query["items", Select @ MemberQ @ "Mr.Wizard", "badge_counts", "bronze"]
```

> ```
> {632}
> ```

Comment: +1 In 10.2, we can use `Import[..., "RawJSON"]` which automatically returns associations.

Comment: @WReach Yes, I noted that in [(87879)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87879/121) -- I guess I should put it here too.