# Cases[data,Colon[key,_]] vs. Cases[data,key:_] toward XPath, XQuery

Tags: programming, syntax, graphs-and-networks, functional-style, data-structures

Exploring methods to index and search tree-structured key:value pairs via named-entity index (key paths) as opposed to Position-based indexing.

- Using `Rule` as `key->value` causes difficulties for `Cases`, which is unfortunate since `Rule` could be combined with `ReplaceAll` to yield lightweight path queries.
- Using `List` as `{key,value}` works but too many parentheses are visually confusing especially in data fusion tasks where multiple datasets are imported separately but must be joined and indexed properly for subsequent analysis.
- Using `Equal` prevents the key from being a string, eg `"key1" = value1 --> "Set::setraw : Cannot assign to raw object key1"`

Why does `Cases` interpret `Colon` shortcut `(key:value_)` differently than `Colon[key,value_]`?

dataR (* for comparison *)

```
 Out[110]= {row1 -> {key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2}, 
 row2 -> {key1 -> value3, key2 -> value4}}

 In[69]:= dataC = dataR /. Rule -> Colon

 Out[69]= {row1 \[Colon] {key1 \[Colon] value1, key2 \[Colon] value2}, 
 row2 \[Colon] {key1 \[Colon] value3, key2 \[Colon] value4}}
```

Then, using `Cases`:

```
 In[113]:= Cases[dataC, Colon[row1  , v_] -> v]

 Out[113]= {{key1 \[Colon] value1, key2 \[Colon] value2}}

 In[114]:= Cases[dataC, (row1 : v_) -> v]

 Out[114]= {row1 \[Colon] {key1 \[Colon] value1, key2 \[Colon] value2},
  row2 \[Colon] {key1 \[Colon] value3, key2 \[Colon] value4}}
```

`Levelspec` can be specified to match the inner keys, eg `key2` at `Level 3`.

Is there a more convenient syntax or method to rapidly restructure arbitrary tree-shaped data? XPath and XQuery, are W3C standards that could be adapted or improved. In particular, XQuery strikes me as being similar in flexibility as Cases in the ability to match and transform data. I've posed similar questions to Wolfram Tech Support. Has been suggested for implementation.

Comment: "I've posed similar questions to Wolfram Tech Support" Did you get any reply?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd like to discuss two points:

#### Cases, destructuring and escaping in patterns

There indeed can be a problem when using `Cases` to destructure expressions involving rules, because `Cases` has an extended syntax which uses rules, and interprets them differently. For example:

```
dataR = {row1 -> {key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2}, 
    row2 -> {key1 -> value3, key2 -> value4}}
```

Here is a naive attempt that will fail:

```
Cases[dataR, row1 -> _]

(* {} *)
```

This will work:

```
Cases[dataR, p : (row1 -> _)]

(* {row1 -> {key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2}} *)
```

The reason is that the colon (which is a short-cut for `Pattern`) serves as an escaping mechanism in this case. The "politically correct" way to perform escaping in patterns is however to use `Verbatim`:

```
Cases[dataR, Verbatim[Rule][row1, _]]

(* {row1 -> {key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2}} *)
```

In some cases, particularly when you only need to collect some parts of the expression involving rules, this may be unnecessary since the escaping will be naturally achieved by the destructuring rule. Example:

```
Cases[dataR, (row1 -> x_) :> x]

(* {{key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2}} *)
```

#### Better ways to destructure trees

You can use the fact that your tree is made of rules, to destructure it better. There were a few questions here about it, particularly [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/extracting-values-from-nested-rules-in-json-data) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-a-trie-be-implemented-efficiently). Let me just show you a simple construct here:

```
ClearAll[destructure];
destructure[tree_, keys__List] :=
   Fold[If[#2 === All, Flatten[#1[[All, 2]]], #2 /. #1] &, tree, keys]
```

This uses the fact that each branch is itself a set of rules. Some examples of use:

```
destructure[dataR,{row1,key1}]

(* value1 *)

destructure[dataR,{row1,All}]

(* {value1,value2} *)

destructure[dataR,{All,All}]

(* {value1,value2,value3,value4} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @LS. That's a great use of Fold. Is there a way to group values by level? That's the behavior of the ReplaceAll path query mechanism: {key2, key1} /. ({row2, row1} /. dataR)

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, you just do this: `destructure[dataR, {{row2, row1}, {key2, key1}}]`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in the second case you used just the normal ASCII colon (the one you get by pressing <kbd>:</kbd>), which expands not to [`Colon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Colon.html?q=Colon&lang=en) but to [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html). If you use the correct colon (<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> in the notebook, `\[Colon]` when typing directly into the kernel or writing a script), you also get the right result:

```
In[8]:= Cases[dataC, Colon[row1 , v_] -> v]

Out[8]= {{key1 : value1, key2 : value2}}

In[9]:= Cases[dataC, (row1 : v_) -> v]

Out[9]= {row1 : {key1 : value1, key2 : value2}, 

>    row2 : {key1 : value3, key2 : value4}}

In[10]:= Cases[dataC, (row1 \[Colon] v_) -> v]

Out[10]= {{key1 : value1, key2 : value2}}
```

The following demonstrates that the normal colon doesn't give `Colon`:

```
In[12]:= (row1 : v_)//FullForm

Out[12]//FullForm= Pattern[row1, Pattern[v, Blank[]]]
```

Comment: Good eye @celtschk. Well, who wants to type \[Colon] every time, that removes the advantage over using List. Any other options?

Comment: You might try to misuse `NonCommutativeMultiply` (`**`). However I'm not sure whether there are any built-in transformations which might become problematic here.

Comment: A Docs link for the `:` operator, [Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html), may be useful. +1

Comment: @kguler: I've now added documentation links for both `Colon` and `Pattern`.