# Use OptionValue to deal with nested options

Tags: programming, options

OptionValue allows for recent versions of Mathematica (I think as from 7) to easily access optional parameters if they are explicitely given to a function or their default values otherwise.

For big functions using options of options can be useful but we don't have in such cases something like OptionValue in order to access them. We must resort to using Replace in order to use them.

See for example the option "LegendGridOptions" in the answer of Jens to the question
[Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4025/66)

```
"LegendGridOptions" -> {Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {.4, .1}}}
```

Has someone already tried to do something like OptionValue for sub-options ?

Comment: In particular, I think [Mr Wizard's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3117/8) to my earlier question is what you want.

Comment: There is another option: feed the options to an internal function. This internal function should be set up with an `Options[...]=` clause, also. Then, it is the sub-function's job to respond to the options.

Comment: I disagree that this is an exact duplicate. While the answer for the question mentioned might be the same, the question is not. The focus of that question is on JASON and not option parsing.

Comment: @Faysal Aberkane, if the answer in link does not help, I have another idea, send me an email and I'll send it to you.

Comment: OK, both answers of Mr Wizard and Heike help, thanks. @ruebenko, I'm still curious about your idea though !

Comment: I also disagree that this is an exact duplicate, even if the answer may be the same. It is a completely different question.

Comment: Also disagree with the closers, this is not an exact duplicate. As to the discussion matter, for my [code highlighter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles/1320#1320), I developed a function `mergeOptions`, whish performs merging of complex option trees. You can find it in the gist linked in that answer, it is fairly small. I was able to do powerful things with it, not sure if `OptionValue` can do that (I did not try very hard though)

Comment: Unless there is some option overlap, would making all the options flat and use FilterRules to select the correct ones to pass to internal calls be of use ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can actually use `OptionValue` to extract options of options by doing something like `OptionValue[option -> subOption]`. For example

```
Options[ff] = {"fruit" -> {apple -> 1, pear -> 2, orange -> 3}}
ff[OptionsPattern[]] := {apple, OptionValue["fruit" -> apple]}

ff["fruit" -> {apple -> 4}]

(* ==> {apple, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

I want to complement the other answers with a construct which allows more general manipulations of options than possible directly with `OptionValue`, while still using `OptionValue` for options extraction. The function, `mergeOptions`, I used for my [real-time code highlighter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles/1320#1320), which involves many nested options, but I will reproduce it here for completeness:

```
ClearAll[optionQ, mergeOptions];
optionQ[opt_] := MatchQ[opt, _Rule | _RuleDelayed];
mergeOptions[x_, y_] := mergeOptions[Null, x, y];
mergeOptions[x_, y_, x_] := y
mergeOptions[x_, fopt_?optionQ, sopts_] := 
    mergeOptions[x, {fopt}, sopts];
mergeOptions[x_, fopts_, sopt_?optionQ] := 
    mergeOptions[x, fopts, {sopt}];
mergeOptions[_, fopts : {__?optionQ}, sopts : {__?optionQ}] :=
    Map[# -> mergeOptions[#, # /. fopts, # /. sopts] &, fopts[[All, 1]]];
mergeOptions[_, x_, y_] := y;
```

It allows one to merge two options trees. For example, here are two option trees:

```
opts1 = {
   a -> {b -> {c -> cc, d -> {e, f}, g -> gg}, h -> {i -> ii, k -> {l, m}}}, 
   n -> o, 
   p -> {q -> {r, s}, t -> {u, v}}
}
```

and

```
opts2 = {a -> {b -> d -> {e1, f1}, h -> i -> iii}, p -> q -> {r1, s1}}
```

And here is the resulting merged tree:

```
mergeOptions[opts1, opts2]

 {
   a -> {b -> {c -> cc, d -> {e1, f1}, g -> gg}, h -> {i -> iii, k -> {l, m}}}, 
   n -> o, 
   p -> {q -> {r1, s1}, t -> {u, v}}
 }
```

Note that `mergeOptions` applies `opts2` as a "patch" on the tree of `opts1`, so effectively for those options which are present in both trees, the options for `opts2` are used.

In cases when options are present in both trees, the results obtained with `mergeOptions` can also be obtained directly with `OptionValue` (as indicated in other answers), for example:

```
OptionValue[{opts2, opts1}, {a -> b -> d}]
```

> `{{e1, f1}}`

```
OptionValue[mergeOptions[opts1, opts2], {a -> b -> d}]
```

> `{{e1, f1}}`

It is when some of the options are only present in one of the trees, that `mergeOptions`  shows an advantage:

```
OptionValue[{opts2,opts1},{a->b->g}]

During evaluation of In[21]:= OptionValue::optnf: Option name a->b->g not 
found in defaults for {{a->{b->d->{e1,f1},h->i->iii},p->q->{r1,s1}},
{a->{b->{c->cc,d->{<<2>>},g->gg},h->{i->ii,k->{<<2>>}}},n->o,p->{q->{r,s},
t->{u,v}}}}. >>

{a->b->g}
```

while with `mergeOptions` we get:

```
OptionValue[mergeOptions[opts1, opts2], {a -> b -> g}]
```

> `{gg}`

This difference is IMO of a big practical importance, since `mergeOptions` allows one to selectively override only those parts of the option tree which are needed, without the need to drag all those which don't change, just to keep the same tree structure. At the same time, the use of `mergeOptions` does not create any ambiguity, since the way trees are merged is completely determined by their structures. In my application (the code highlighter mentioned above), this allowed me to generate highlighter packages with really minimal explicit option specifications, since the defaults took care of most common settings, and I did not have to drag them around.

Answer (score 8):

Elaborating on Heike's suggestion here is an example where functions with different options call each other:

```
ClearAll[gg, ff]
Options[gg] = {apple -> 1, pear -> 2, orange -> 3}
Options[ff] = {"blah" -> blub, "fruit" -> Options[gg]}

ff[opts : OptionsPattern[ff]] := Block[{},
  Print[OptionValue["blah"]];
  Print[OptionValue["fruit"]];
  gg[OptionValue["fruit"]];
  ]
gg[OptionsPattern[gg]] := Block[{},
  Print[OptionValue[pear]];
  ]
```

Then

```
ff[]
(*
blub
{apple -> 1, pear -> 2, orange -> 3}
2 
*)
```

And

```
ff["fruit" -> {pear -> 22}]
(*
blub
{pear -> 22}
22
*)
```

And

```
gg[pear -> 22]
(*22*)
```