# What is recommended way to define my function option

Tags: programming, options

In Mathematica 5.x days many packages used the following standard mechanism to read option values

```
Options[myfun]={myQuiet->True};

myfun[arg_,opts___?OptionQ]:=Module[{theQuiet},
theQuiet=((myQuiet/.{opts})/.Options[myfun,myQuiet]);
someCode
]
```

However it does not cover passing values of more complex options like
**myMethod->{"TensorProduct", myOrdering->1,myStart->someValue}**

Sure I can use First/Rest commands to read values of myMethod suboptions, however, I would like to know what is the standard/recommended way to deal with suboptions and how to set their default values.

Comment: Have you seen [Dealing with nested options](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4753/14303)?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't seen beforer, however it is not about the same think I want. My wish to learn how for example NDSolve[system, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5, 
    "Coefficients" -> DOPRICoefficients}]; options are passed.